# Execute postgres SQL script with password through NIFI

Tags: postgresql, shell, apache-nifi

In a NIFI flow, I want to run a **.sql** file in a PostgreSQL database.

so I created a shell script file as below and execute it using **ExecuteStreamCommand** processor,

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -d dbName -U user -W  -f file.sql
```

My concern is that when we execute `psql -d dbName -U user -W  -f file.sql` via terminal it asks for the psql password as below

also i tried `PGPASSWORD=mypw psql -d dbName -U user -W  -f file.sql` but it also requested to enter the password

[image: as below image]

I tried to pass the password as the parameter via shell script but it didn't works

Since I have a little bit of experience with shell scripts, I have no idea how to provide the password via shell script or any other way to achive this.

Could you please advise me on this?

Comment: Take a look at: [How to use psql with no password prompt?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt)

Comment: @Luuk I tried this aslo`PGPASSWORD=mypw psql -d dbName -U user -W  -f file.sql` this also expects the password

Comment: `-W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)`, so you should leave out the option `-W` ?  (see: `psql -?` )

Comment: yeah now it works thank you, @Luuk canyou please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question has been give on dba.stackexchange.com:

[How to use psql with no password prompt?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt)

Also specify only parameters to `psql`, which are really needed. For an overview of parameters use `psql -?`  (see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html )

In this case the option `-W` was making sure the password was always asked.